# Android Activity lifecycle testing

Tags: android, unit-testing

I have Activity, which is to save its data in case system decides to kill it while it is in the background.
So, I’ve got onSaveInstanceState:

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState){
    outState.putString("value", "some_value");
}
```

I check whether Bundle object is null in onCreate:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    isRestarted=(savedInstanceState==null);
```

How do I write test method? I tried

```
    public void testRecreate(){
    Instrumentation mInstr=this.getInstrumentation();
    mInstr.callActivityOnSaveInstanceState(mActivity, null);
    mActivity.finish();
    mActivity=this.getActivity();
    assertEquals(false, mActivity.isRestarted);
}
```

but it seems to be wrong.

Answer (score 6):

You can use some hidden API functionality. In your test's setup, call the

```
android.app.ActivityManagerNative.getDefault().setAlwaysFinish()
```

method via reflection (because it's a hidden API) and confirm that the value was successfully set using

```
android.provider.Settings.System.getInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.System.ALWAYS_FINISH_ACTIVITIES, 0)
```

Then in the test cleanup, set this setting back to false.

Enabling the `AlwaysFinish` setting causes the system to destroy activities as soon as they are no longer on the screen, immediately triggering the onSaveInstanceState event. For this code to work, you will need the `ALWAYS_FINISH` and `WRITE_SETTINGS` permissions.

See the code for the SetAlwaysFinish tool linked in this blog: [How to test onSaveInstanceState and onRestoreInstanceState on a real device](http://bricolsoftconsulting.com/how-to-test-onsaveinstancestate-and-onrestoreinstancestate-on-a-real-device/)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to put this together Theo. Nice work!

Comment: I could not get the setAlwaysFinish.apk to work on Android 4.0.3. It launched, but checking the check box did not have any effect. Just a warning. If onCreate is NOT called after the activity is supposed to have been finished, setAlwaysFinish does not do the job.

Answer (score 2):

For manual testing, this routine works:

1. Launch the activity you want to test
2. Hit the home menu button on your device (activity is stopped)
3. Kill the process from [DDMS](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/ddms.html) (activity is still [not destroyed](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html))
4. Bring back your app again from the [recent apps list](http://www.android.com/images/ics/tasks-sm.png)

This should trigger `onCreate` again on your activity while *not* restarting the entire application. If you're not saving and loading the state properly, you'll know soon enough.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't been through it before, I found it worthwhile to [do this](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/testing/activity_test.html) at least once.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/testing/activity_test.html => broken link :(

Comment: I've been through it but my problem seems to be a little bit more complicated

Answer (score 0):

Stuff like that could be easily test using [robolectric](http://pivotal.github.com/robolectric/). Check it out!